# A Simple Antisymmetric Masyu

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, masyu

The standard [Masyu](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html) rules apply.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the puzzle, I enjoyed solving it long after the quick draw guys gave the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Some initial deductions will allow us to fill in some squares rapidly, especially using the edges. 
>  [image: Masyu_1_1]

> Focusing on the top, the white circle in R1C7 can only be connected to the white circle in R1C3. At the bottom, the white circle in R11C7 must also be connected vertically. This allows us to solve for the lower right and make some progress towards the left side.
>  [image: Masyu_1_2]

> We can then complete some of the connections on the upper right of the grid, because most of these connections only have 1 way to go. 
>  [image: Masyu_1_3]

> Next,we focus on the lower left making sure to connect them legally. 
>  [image: Masyu_1_4]

> Finally, focusing on the upper left, we are only left with a few more connections and we need to make sure to not to close the loop too early. And we are done! 
>  [image: Masyu_1_5]

Comment: Sniped! I spend too much time re-considering how many deductions I should show.

Comment: This is correct, well done! :D